# Emulating private methods with closures vs public methods in objects

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, private

As [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) closures are used to emulate private methods for the *module pattern*:

```
var counter = (function () {
    var privateCounter = 0;

    function changeBy(val) {
        privateCounter += val;
    }

    return {
        increment: function () {
            changeBy(1);
        },
        decrement: function() {
            changeBy(-1);
        }
    };
}());
```

However, instead of using the module pattern we can also create a class instead. What is the advantage of creating a class over using the module pattern?

```
function Counter() {
    var privateCounter = 0;

    function changeBy(val) {
        privateCounter += val;
    }

    this.increment = function() {
        changeBy(1);
    };

    this.decrement = function() {
        changeBy(-1);
    };
}

var counter = new Counter();
```

Comment: You still are using closures for privacy here. Only you've created a constructor, not a singleton module. It's more like the `makeCounter` function presented below that.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the advantage of creating a class over using the module pattern?

The advantage of creating a class over using the module pattern is that you can create several instances of a class:

```
var counter1 = new Counter;
var counter2 = new Counter;
```

Each instance will have its own set of private variables.

On the other hand, when you use the module pattern, you are only creating a single object (often called a singleton, namespace or module). Again, it has it's own set of private variables.

Both the module pattern and the class have their own uses. The module pattern is useful for creating modules, manager objects (of which only one instance must exist), etc.

The class pattern is useful for creating new data structures of the same type. For example, a linked list data structure would be modeled as a class and not as a singleton or a module.